# Why I am getting '[Error] Execution (48: 50): ORA-00936: missing expression'

Tags: sql, oracle

```
      SELECT CASE
            WHEN(SELECT TO_CHAR(A.BILL_DT, 'MM') )  >= 4
            THEN
               CONCAT (SELECT TO_CHAR(A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY') ),(SELECT TO_CHAR(A.BILL_DT+1, 'YYYY')  )
            ELSE
               CONCAT (SELECT TO_CHAR(A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY')  ) - 1, (SELECT TO_CHAR(A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY')   ))
         END AS FY,
         SUM (A.BILL_AMT)
    FROM REVADMIN.REV_BILL_HEADER A
GROUP BY CASE
            WHEN (SELECT TO_CHAR(A.BILL_DT, 'MM')  ) >= 4
            THEN
               CONCAT(SELECT TO_CHAR(A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY')), (SELECT TO_CHAR(A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY')) + 1)
            ELSE
               CONCAT (SELECT TO_CHAR(A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY' )) - 1, (SELECT TO_CHAR(A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY' ))
         END;
```

This supposed to be true but still getting error why am getting missing expression error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `SELECT` from `CASE` expression; just use column from the table in `FROM` clause.

For simplicity, I also removed `concat` and used the double pipe `||` concatenation operator.

(Though, I'm not sure what is that piece of code supposed to return, doesn't make much sense to me but I guess you know.)

```
  SELECT CASE
            WHEN TO_CHAR (A.BILL_DT, 'MM') >= 4
            THEN
               TO_CHAR (A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY') || TO_CHAR (A.BILL_DT + 1, 'YYYY')
            ELSE
               TO_CHAR (A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY') - 1 || TO_CHAR (A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY')
         END AS FY,
         SUM (A.BILL_AMT)
    FROM REVADMIN.REV_BILL_HEADER A
GROUP BY CASE
            WHEN TO_CHAR (A.BILL_DT, 'MM') >= 4
            THEN
               TO_CHAR (A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY') || TO_CHAR (A.BILL_DT + 1, 'YYYY')
            ELSE
               TO_CHAR (A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY') - 1 || TO_CHAR (A.BILL_DT, 'YYYY')
         END
```

Comment: Many Thanks Buddy this query finally works.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems the 'SELECT's right before your column expressions shouldn't be there, like

```
WHEN( TO_CHAR(A.BILL_DT, 'MM') )  >= 4
```

instead of

```
WHEN(SELECT TO_CHAR(A.BILL_DT, 'MM') )  >= 4
```

(For that case, I'd still be wondering whether your to_char() will be correctly compared to a number value.)